# Training Register automation email

Tags: scripting

I'm very new to google sheets
I am wanting to know if can get it to do what I want it to do. if so Ill do some more reading to work it out or if you can point me in the right direction
I have a training register that I want it to email the person that their particular training is going to be out of date in say a month.
All people are in rows and Training in the columns

I see a lot of threads about this but no one gets a reply on this topic.

Hello Pierre thanks for you input I really appreciate it

Like said Pierre im very new to this so I was still researching code. I found this but I dont think this will do what I want to.

I do want the first and last name columns and email in C

```
function sendMail(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   //Get the active Spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');     //Get the sheet by name, Sheet1 as example
  var startRow = 2;     //We start process things from row 2
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();    //Get the last row of data to be processed
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  // Get the last column of data to be processed
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,lastCol);  //Fetch the range
  var data = range.getValues();   //Get the values inside the range
      for (var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){   //Iterate values
        var row = data[i];   //Set up variable for easier retrieve data to be processed and more understandable by human
        var FirstName = row[1];  //Column B
        var LastName = row[2];   //Column C
        var emailAddress = row[3];  //Column D
        var dueDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[4]),'GMT+0800','dd/MM/yyyy');   //Column E. Utilities format so the date won't be in long values
        var timer = row[6];  //Column G
        var msg = 'Hello '+FirstName+' '+LastName+'<br><br>'   // Your templates
                 +'This is a test mail '+dueDate+'<br><br>'
                 +'Bla bla bla<br>'
                 +'Another lines of texts<br><br>'
                 +'Another lines of texts<br><br>'
                 +'Thank You<br><br>'
                 +'OH!! I like Banana.';
            if(timer ==3){   //Set up the condition
            GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,'Your Renty Rental is Due Soon!',msg,{htmlBody:msg})   //Send the email to the recipient
            sheet.getRange(startRow+i,7).setNote('Email Sent');  //Set note on column 'G' 
            SpreadsheetApp.flush
            }
    }
};
```

Here is a link to my sheet ( have removed all my scrips as im starting from scrach https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cwkbBAEoX4Wzo0d_sS0UrCYtTYMo5S9NHBSlSmat4CA/edit?usp=sharing

I do want want the first name in column A an last name column B email column c.

In columns F,J,K,U,V,W,AB,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AM,AN,AR,AZ I want them to email the person at 30days before it runs out and again at 15day before it runs out over all rows in each sheet and in all other columns I don't want it to email as they don't run out ever.

I do have multiple sheets that I need this code to work on.

I have worked on the basics and I have had the sheet emailing out, but adding all the extra requirements I need will require a lot knowledge.

Comment: Can you give us a view of your sheet and maybe the code that you wrote ?

Comment: If the questions are similar to this, then that is the problem. StackOverflow is not meant for questions like these. The general gist is: you have code and a problem. You show us the code, we suggest solutions or what the problem could be. Short answer: yes that is easily doable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Jarrad: I don't know if I'm the only one, but your sheet is a mess. I don't get the point of your differents colums. Can you please explain the point of the different columns ?

Comment: @Pierre Each column is for a different qualification that each person needs. So I want to make the sheet email that person automatically  that they have a qualification that has run out or going to run out in 30days. so I dont have to manually look for out of date qualifications.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your table like:

[image: Exemple of content]

You can use the code below:

```
function sendReminder() {

  // Get the sheet where you get your register
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Training Register"); 

  // Get the data, consider you have a table with 3 columns "name", "end date" and "email"
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 

  for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){

    var d = new Date();

    // If the date is today or before, we send the reminder
    if(data[i][1] < d){

      GmailApp.sendEmail(data[i][2], "Particular training", "Your particular training is out of date");

    }

  }

}
```

You will also need to create a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to run the code once every time you want.

Comment: Details added above

Comment: Any ideas guys ??